# Django render a form field with css using crispy forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I have a form I want to render with crispy form,

FORM

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        excludes = ('user', 'created')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False ## I only need the input field
        self.helper.layout = layout.Layout(

            layout.Field('name', css_class="form-control"), 
            layout.Field('objective', css_class="form-control"),
            ## ADD CLASS form-control TO THE FIELDS (This is the problem since the fields are not rendered with the class)
        )
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

TEMPLATE

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltips" data-original-title="Lorem Ipsum" data-html="true" data-placement="right" data-container="body"></i></label>
    {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.name.errors|striptags }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Theme/ Objective <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltips" data-original-title="Lorem Ipsum" data-html="true" data-placement="right" data-container="body"></i></label>
    {{ form.objective|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.objective.errors|striptags }}
</div>
```

The fields are not rendered with the class `form-control`. 
The labels are rendered and I don't need them since I have my custom labels.
Any help on how I can render the fields with the class will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you consider skipping `crispy-forms` and rendering your form manually https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: @Selcuk. Thanks for the suggestion, how will I add the class form-control in the fields?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render your fields manually, you can add them like:

```
<input type="text" name="{{ form.objective.html_name }}" 
       id={{ form.objective.id_for_label }}" 
       class="form-control">
```

Please note that this will require you to render all your `input`s manually.